# C# String.Length from Microsoft Documentation

Tags: c#, string, string-length

[Microsoft documentation states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that this code will return 7 characters

> The Length property returns the number of Char objects in this instance, 
>       not the number of Unicode characters.

```
string characters = "abc\u0000def";
Console.WriteLine(characters.Length);    // Displays 7
```

I will need a function to return as result 12 because there are 12 different characters. Which function I may use?

Comment: "there are 12 different characters" - no, there's 7 - `\u0000` is _one character_.  What are you doing with it that you need to treat it as through it has 12 characters?

Comment: Funny. Why do you think those are 12 characters? You are aware that 6 of them form one unicode character and are interpreted by the compiler?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to have a string literal with its characters not interpreted as escape sequences? Because once you have a seven-character string, it's a seven character string; there's no unambiguous way to turn it into a 12-character string again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would have to prevent the interpretation of the literal by the compiler. This can be done with the @ prefix, like this:

```
var characters = @"abc\u0000def";
```

The `Length` property of this string will then return 12, but there will no longer be an actual unicode character in the string.

Comment: Beat me to it. The catch here is that `there will no longer be an actual unicode character in the string` if you use it escaped.

Answer (score 4):

The C# compiler will replace `\u0000` by a null byte. That means, at execution time you will simply have only 7 characters in your memory.

If you don't want the compiler to replace the special char, you have to escape the backslash in the first place:

```
string characters = "abc\\u0000def";
Console.WriteLine(characters.Length);    // Displays 12
```